# What is the datatype of "formula" for the e1071 package in R?

Tags: r

I am learning R's e1071 package to perform naive Bayes analysis. According to [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/e1071/docs/naiveBayes) tutorial, the package's naieveBayes method takes an input called "formula" -- which it says is "A formula of the form class ~ x1 + x2 + .."

How do I create such a formula? I have a dataset with gender, job and income columns and want to perform analysis on each of those dimensions/factors. Do I need to somehow turn them into a formula object? (I'm pretty new to R so I am unclear if R even supports specific data types like formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typing `~ x1 + x2` will create an object of the class `formula`.

Look at `?lm` for examples of the basic idea.  The domain-specific language is pretty flexible, so different models use it in different ways.

For instance:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
lm( y ~ x, data=dat)
f <- y ~ x
class(f)
lm( f, data=dat )
```

Comment: how do I assign my parameters to X and Y?

Comment: That's not the way to think of it.  The formula defines a set of instructions, which the model will use to interpret what to do.  Look at the `lm` example above.  `lm` is fed two arguments: the formula, and the data.  The formula tells it what to do with the data.

Comment: B Friedman so to make an imaginary analogy, if you wanted to perform regression with an pretend function regressionthis() which worked like lm() then you would feed it a formula of y=mx+b if you wanted it to find a linear model?

Comment: @abe3 It would depend entirely on what `regressionthis` wanted out of a formula.  Different functions will handle them differently.  The key is that a formula is a set of instructions to the model which the model knows how to interpret.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see I have to learn a little bit more before I can use this function. Is it fair to say  that a formula is a kind of data type in R that gives instructions to a model?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to point out that `?formula` will create a formula-class object.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are created by the use of the `~` function. It can be used either as a prefix operator or an infix operator:

```
form <- ~ atom
form <- atomA ~ atomB
is.function(`~`)
[1] TRUE

class(form[[2]])
#[1] "name"
 is.language(form)
#[1] TRUE
 is.language(form[[2]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Just like functions, formula objects get created with an environment:

```
str(form)
#Class 'formula' length 3 atomA ~ atomB
#  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Different functions have different assumptions about which form (prefix or infix) to use. You can extract the components by positional number using list indexing. The first element will always be the tilde operator.

```
form[[1]]
# returns:  ~> 
form[[2]]
# atomA
form[[3]]
# atomB
```

You can demote a formula to a character object with `as.character` or promote a character object to a formula with `as.formula`. The `formula` function does not create formulas, but is rather a generic function that has specific behavior with different classed objects, generally serving to extract a formula from a regression object.

```
 methods(formula)
#-----------
 [1] formula.character*           
 [2] formula.data.frame*          
 [3] formula.default*             
 [4] formula.formula*             
 [5] formula.glm*                 
 [6] formula.lm*                  
 [7] formula.nls*                 
 [8] formula.quantmod*            
 [9] formula.summary.formula.cross
```

Your results for methods(formula) will differ depending on which packages you have loaded at the time.
    [10] formula.terms*